# $.fn.fixTime not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

> http://jsfiddle.net/AVLzH/14/

I'm trying to build my first jQuery extended function which will take the time format from `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` and convert it to readable things like `Just a moment ago` or `2 hours ago` my code worked perfectly before I made it into an extended function.

> **Sidebar:** yes I know its better to use Server-side code to get the current time, this is just for example purposes

When I call the function its in a chain that grabs the `datetime` attribute from all `<time>` elements, and switches the text with whats returned and sets the old text to `data-tooltip`.

There's a lot of code so its probably best you check out the jsfiddle page:

> http://jsfiddle.net/AVLzH/14/

<s>jsLint is returning the following errors:</s>

```
Error:
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
});

Expected '(end)' and instead saw '}'.
})( jQuery );

Implied global: jQuery 3, console 19,20,22,23,40,50,75
```

Yeah and basically I have no clue what to do about this.

Thanks for any help ahead of time!

> http://jsfiddle.net/AVLzH/14/

PS - accidently put old code in there.. changed link

Thanks for all your help so far.. jsLint is no longer returning any errors, but its not executing correctly.

Comment: Your code reveals a deep misunderstanding of how jQuery works. I recommend reading up on jQuery Chaining: http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/ and rereading the docs on plugin authoring http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Here's your code w/o the syntax errors:
http://jsfiddle.net/andromedado/DsTGu/
(though there are still other types of errors in there ;)

Answer (score 2):

The part after returning is wrong

```
 return returning;
    };
});

})( jQuery );
```

, it should read:

```
  return returning;
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Try the JSLint button at Jsfiddle to check your syntax.

```
(function( $ ) {

    jQuery.fn.fixTime = function(activityTime) {



            var currentTime = new Date(),
                month  = currentTime.getMonth() + 1,
                day    = currentTime.getDate(),
                year   = currentTime.getFullYear(),
                hour   = currentTime.getHours(),
                minute = currentTime.getMinutes(),
                second = currentTime.getSeconds(),
                activityTime = new Date(parseInt(this.attr('datetime'), 10)),
                masterTime = (year*10000000000) + (month*100000000) + (day*1000000) + (hour*10000) + (minute*100) + (second * 1),
                timeDifference = masterTime - activityTime,
                returning;

            console.log("Current Time: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);    
            console.log("Current Time: " + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);

            console.log("Current Time:  " + masterTime);
            console.log("Activity Time: " + activityTime, this);

        console.log(this.attr('datetime'))
            console.log(new Date(20120211103802))
            // Change Time 
            timeDifference = timeDifference + 0;

            // YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

            //             60 - 1 Min
            //           6000 - 1 Hour
            //         240000 - 1 Day
            //        7000000 - 1 Week
            //       30000000 - 1 Month
            //    10000000000 - 1 Year

            // YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

            console.log("Time Difference: " + timeDifference);

            if (0 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 60) {
                returning = "Just a moment ago";
            } else if (60 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 120) {
                returning = "A minute ago";
            } else if (120 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 6000) {
                timeDifference = Math.floor(timeDifference/100);
                returning = timeDifference + " minutes ago";
            } else if (6000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 20000) {
                console.log("1 hour ago");
            } else if (20000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 240000) {
                timeDifference = Math.floor(timeDifference/10000);
                returning = timeDifference + " hours ago";
            } else if (240000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 2000000) {
                returning = "Yesterday";
            } else if (2000000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 7000000) {
                timeDifference = Math.floor(timeDifference/1000000);
                returning = timeDifference + " days ago";
            } else if (7000000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 14000000) {
                return "A week ago";
            } else if (14000000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 30000000) {
                timeDifference = Math.floor(timeDifference/7000000);
                returning = timeDifference + " weeks ago";
            } else if (30000000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 200000000) {
                returning = "A month ago";
            } else if (200000000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 10000000000) {
                timeDifference = Math.floor(timeDifference/100000000);
                returning = timeDifference + " months ago";
            } else if (10000000000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 20000000000) {
                returning = "A year ago";
            } else if (20000000000 <= timeDifference && timeDifference < 1000000000000) {
                timeDifference = Math.floor(timeDifference/10000000000);
                returning = timeDifference + " years ago";
            } else {
                console.error("Error Calculating"); // Only when less than zero or longer than 100 years
                returning = "undefined";
            }

            return returning;
        };

}( jQuery ));

(function() {

    var times = $('time');

    times.each(function() {
        var beforeTime = $(this).text();
   //     var betterTime = new Date($(this).attr('datetime'));

        var betterTime = $(this).fixTime();

        $(this).text(betterTime).attr('data-tooltip', beforeTime);
    });

})();
```

Comment: That's because you are calling the method against a string, not a jQuery object.